# Create a policy template class with a policy template class factory?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to create a templated class factory method that in turn creates a templated class itself inheriting from policy templates. Here is what I've tried for the factory method:

```
template <typename T, template <class Created> class CreationPolicy>
class WidgetManager : public CreationPolicy<Widget<T>>
{
public:
  WidgetManager() {};
  static Widget<T>* doAll(){
    Widget<T> *t = WidgetManager::Create(); //the static create method comes from CreationPolicy
    return t;
  }
};
```

But the Widget I would like to make should itself inherit from a template policy class:

```
template<template <class Created> class IntPolicy>
class Widget : public IntPolicy<Widget>
{};
```

with `IntPolicy` like so:

```
template <class T>
struct BigInt
{
  int LOGNOW = 99;
};

template <class T>
struct SmallInt
{
  int LOGNOW = 5;
};
```

What's the proper syntax to do this? Everything I have tried gives me type errors. For example, the above gives "`template argument 1 is invalid`" or `"type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for <template <template<class Created> class IntPolicy> class Widget`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess thinking in terms of type level functions helps:

`Widget` needs a template which requires 1 type to become itself a complete type:

```
Widget :: (* -> *) -> *
```

So whatever `T` in `Widget<T>` is, it needs to be a template accepting one complete type (`* -> *`). But what is `T` in your case? A `typename T` (`*`). You cannot use the template `BigInt` for that.

So I guess changing that `typename T` to a `template <class> class T` should do the trick.